# JS checking an existing key returns undefined for an object

Tags: javascript

Recently, I was encountering undefined error for the value when accessed in JavaScript object key.
I got the arrays of object using the `mongoose.find().exec()` callback and I was validating for each object has a particular key.

Here is the sample object

```
 {"promo_id":"5af1c07d5542fc9307847a6a",
  "__v":0,
   "description":"Hello", 
 "available_count":0}
```

- When I tried to do the test `obj.hasOwnProperty('available_count')`
  it returned `false`
- When I tested object against `lodash` `_.isObject()` it returned me true.
- Finally I am using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to make
  it work.

It will be great why this wired behavior is being encountered.

```js
let o = {"promo_id":"5af1c07d5542fc9307847a6a",
  "__v":0,
   "description":"Hello", 
 "available_count":0}
 
 let result = o.hasOwnProperty('available_count');
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Are you sure it returns false and not 0?

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then immediately parsing `obj`? If it's JSON you should just parse it. If it's an object, don't do anything to it.

Comment: I put your code in a code snippet just as you describe. `obj.hasOwnProperty('available_count')` returns `true` as demonstrated. Can you further explain why you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is exactly the same as `obj` and is unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe it inherits the property? What does `'available_count' in obj` return?

Comment: It return `undefined`

Comment: for me `o.hasOwnProperty('available_count');` returns `true` it returns true currently, for the given object.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(up), up.hasOwnProperty('available_count'));`  here is the log for the real code statement `{"_id":"5af3da805da54d9c810d09d8","promo_id":"5af1c07d5542fc9307847a6a","__v":0,"description":"free shipping...! Order today!","start_date":"2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z","end_date":"2018-05-22T00:00:00.000Z","usage_limit":{"max":-1,"max_per_user":7,"used_count":36},"available_count":0} false`

Comment: `'available_count' in obj` can't evaluate to `undefined`. It is a boolean expression that always evaluates to either `true` or `false`. Try logging that: `console.log( 'available_count' in up );`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Mongoose docs, [`query.find()`, returns an array of documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find).  Mongoose documents are not JS literal objects:

> Mongoose documents represent a one-to-one mapping to documents as stored in MongoDB. Each document is an instance of its Model.
>
> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

If you check for the [Document API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document), you'll see that it has a [toObject() method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject). I suggest you to try that in the first item of the returned array.

But you still may ask why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` works for you. Well, if you check the [MDN doc on `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you will realize that it looks for a [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) in the object being stringified, if it has implemented that method, it will customize the stringification behavior. And guess what? Yep, [mongoose documents implement that method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON), then your document will be correctly stringified into a JS Object Literal, and again parsed by your call to `JSON.parse`.